# Trigger 'Choose default app' dialog for SMS

Tags: android, sms

I'm sure this is quite easy but I can't figure it out from the documentation.

I'm making an SMS application for Android, it sends and receives messages just fine.
However, when a SMS get's received the standard notification show up (which is what I want) but if I click the message from the notifications bar it doesn't show the 'Choose which app to open this with' dialog. It opens it with the standard SMS app.

If I install another SMS app (like Handcent) and do the same thing the dialog pops up and I'm able to choose between Handcent and the standard client (but not my app).

How do I tell the system that 'Hey! I'm also able to open SMS message'?

Thanks in advance.